# Get notified when picture is added or removed from album

Tags: ios

I want to get notified when a new photo is added or deleted from an album in the `Photos.app`. Specifically in `iCloud Photos`. Docs suggest to use Photos.framework [PHPhotoLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHPhotoLibrary/registerChangeObserver:) to fetch a list of assets and register an observer.

So that is what I did but observer is never called.

```
@implementation PhotoChangesObserver
- (void)photoLibraryDidChange:(PHChange *)changeInstance {
    NSLog(@"%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, changeInstance);
}
@end

[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary]registerChangeObserver:[PhotoChangesObserver new]];
PHFetchResult *res = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:nil];
NSLog(@"fetchAssetsWithOptions res: %@\n%d"); // 8 results
```

Then I go to the `Photos.app` and delete a couple of photos and go back to my app to trigger another fetch and indeed I get 6 results only. But the observer was never called.

```
PHFetchResult *res = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:nil];
NSLog(@"fetchAssetsWithOptions res: %@\n%d"); // 6 results after deletion
```

Is the observer supposed to be called in this case or is only for edits  to pictures (like add a filter, cropped, etc)?

I have tried adding other photos into a shared album. But the total